# Run Boto with EC2 in Python with importing errors

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

With the Access Key & Secret Key located at my home directory, when I run the following in the command line:

```
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
conn = EC2Connection()
```

The console does not show any error but when I place the exact command in the python script. It displays an error, "No module named boto.ec2.connection".

Does anyone know why this error occur?

Comment: just try import boto to test... see what happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just solve my problem after taking a short break. Yeah~!

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto
```

Python-boto package must be install for the connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this error on RHEL do this...

```
sudo yum install -y python-boto
sudo pip install boto
```